# Passenger isn't running but no errors in the logs

Tags: apache, passenger, passenger-apache

I am trying to get Passenger set up to work with Apache. Passenger starts, but then stops without reporting an error in the apache.log. Here's my config:

```
<VirtualHost *:3000>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/apps/mtga-tracker/public
PassengerStickySessions on
PassengerDisableAnonymousTelemetry on

<Directory "/var/www/apps/mtga-tracker/public">
      Options FollowSymLinks
      Require all granted
      PassengerEnabled on
</Directory>

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

And here is my relevant Apache config:

```
PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/passenger-6.0.17
PassengerDisableAnonymousTelemetry on
```

And passenger.conf:

PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby

Here's the tail of Apache's error.log:

```
    [ N 2023-05-25 21:44:40.5917 26413/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1377 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
    [ N 2023-05-25 21:44:40.6251 26454/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1340 ]: Starting Passenger core...
    [ N 2023-05-25 21:44:40.6252 26454/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
    [ N 2023-05-25 21:44:40.6326 26454/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1015 ]: Passenger core online, PID 26454
    [Thu May 25 21:44:40.635314 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 26399:tid 140603631708032] AH00489: Apache/
2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/6.0.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu May 25 21:44:40.635671 2023] [core:notice] [pid 26399:tid 140603631708032] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[ N 2023-05-25 21:44:43.1261 26454/T4 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:519 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
```

But the results of `passenger-status` are this:

```
    ERROR: Phusion Passenger(R) doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure that it is running, then the causes of this problem could be:

1. You customized the instance registry directory using Apache's PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger(R) Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command line argument. If so, please set the environment variable PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR to that directory and run passenger-status again.
2. The instance directory has been removed by an operating system background service. Please set a different instance registry directory using Apache's PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger(R) Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command line argument.
```

I'm not sure where else to look.

Any suggestions?